# scp.SCPException: ser **** (100) may not copy files

Tags: python, scp

I'm not sure why I see this error message at times and other times the scp succeeds without any issues. How do I fix it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/jenkins/workspace/team-infra-networking/superloop_pull_cfgs_prod/lib/objects/basenode.py", line 117, in pull_cfgs
    self.scp_connect.scp_get_file('/var/local/ucs/config.ucs', '{}/superloop/data/{}/{}{}/{}.ucs'.format(self.get_home_directory(),self.get_subdir(scp_flag),self.get_region(),self.get_environment(),self.hostname))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/netmiko/scp_handler.py", line 45, in scp_get_file
    self.scp_client.get(source_file, dest_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scp.py", line 238, in get
    self._recv_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scp.py", line 388, in _recv_all
    raise SCPException(asunicode(msg[1:]))
scp.SCPException: ser **** (100) may not copy files (scp -f /var/local/ucs/config.ucs)
```

I'm able to initiate a regular scp command via bash and it works fine every time.

Comment: Check the logs of the remote device.

Comment: I see this: err shell: User rancid (100) may not copy files (scp -f /var/local/ucs/config.ucs)